# Newline Character in pdf file writing to next line in python

Tags: python

I tried to read the pdf file as source in Python script and converted to text File/Format but for every line that is read from pdf, the last character(CAT Column) is being pushed to next line.
How can this be handled,so that data is converted AS IS from pdf to text.

Source "PDF" File:
CODE Description   CAT
0011 TEST DATA ABC P
0012 SAMP Data EFG C

Converted Data to "Text":
0011TEST DATA ABC
P0012SAMP Data EFG

Comment: Below is the code snippet but the last character is printing in the next line:  import PyPDF2
import collections

def main():
        

 pdfFile = open("file.pdf", 'rb') 
 pdfRead = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)        



 number_of_pages = pdfRead.getNumPages()
 c = collections.Counter(range(number_of_pages))
 for i in c:
    page = pdfRead.getPage(i)   
    page_content = page.extractText()  
  
    print (page_content)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()

Comment: Can someone please help on this.